# force:createRecord being called from a Lightning App

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I followed the instructions in this blog post to create a Lightning component using force:createrecord -

http://www.infallibletechie.com/2017/11/forcecreaterecord-example-in-salesforce.html

I was able to get this to work perfectly fine.  I then created a Lightning app which wrapped the component:

In Dev Console, I then clciked on Preview, and it brought up the button in the component.  But when I clicked the button, the call to force:createRecord failed.  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

I have came across this issue recently and found that this is how `force:createRecord` event works. The error I see when I debug:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
>   Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]
>   Callback failed: apex://customFieldController/ACTION$getRecId
>   Failing descriptor: {c:customComp}

And in the official [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_createRecord.htm), it was mentioned:

> This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience, Salesforce app, and Lightning communities.

I bet you will not see this error if you have had this component on a Community page. Because, that's how I finally did my testing for force:createRecord event.

Comment: It should work well on a community page. Regarding the error: Whenever this force:createRecord event gets fired on a Lightning App, I get this error message on my screen.

Comment: As you said from the documentation, this looks like a problem when using ANY event outside LEX, not just force:createRecord.  The "top" Level for the Documentation on using Events says:

"If you fire one of these force or lightning events in your Lightning apps or components outside of the Salesforce app or Lightning Experience:
You must handle the event by using the <aura:handler> tag in the handling component.
Use the <aura:registerEvent> or <aura:dependency> tags to ensure that the event is sent to the client, when needed."

So does anyone have an example of how to do this?